# TalkBack - how to read string with literal punctuation?

Tags: android, screen-readers, talkback

My app needs to display numeric ranges in a TextView, such as "34-93". TalkBack is reading this as "thirty-four minus ninety-three". I want it to either read "thirty-four dash ninety-three" or "thirty-four to ninety-three" I've tried inserting spaces before and after the dash, as well as using both a hyphen and en-dash, to no avail. In general, though, I have little control over how this string is formatted.

It seems  like it should read "dash" if there were some attribute to cause it to read punctuation literally, like [accessibilitySpeechPunctuation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1620201-accessibilityspeechpunctuation) in iOS.